# SQL Server 2016 Create Trigger to start after New Table is finished updating

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table that is pushed to me from another SQL Server.  The table is dropped after it is rotated to a "Current Day" table (Current Data is rotated to prev day before this).

Currently we have jobs that are running to do the "rotating" that are set at a specific time.  I had originally created a trigger but clearly a trigger won't work (as I figured out from the comments) since the DDL operation wont continue its flow until after this trigger is complete... It also looks like this is just not possible since I don't have control over the group that is pushing the data to us.

Resolution : I went to the org that pushes the data and requested they add a step that inserts a record into a TableLog table and I am doing my trigger off of that insert instead.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertTest
ON [pace].[Table_Load_Log] 
after insert
AS 

if exists(select Table_name from inserted where inserted.Table_name = 'POE_Task_Details_SE_TEMP')
BEGIN
    --drop table dbo.newtable   
    exec dbo.sp_start_job N'Make Pace Tables From Temp Table Push’
END 

GO
```

Comment: What is your question here? In all honestly, this looks like a terrible idea. If the table `dbo.TestTable` has rows in it and the number keeps changing, then your `CREATE` statement will never finish. This looks, and feels, very much like an XY problem; what is the problem you're actually trying to solve here?

Comment: What happens to `dbo.NewTable` on a new cycle? I don't see you dropping it but recreating it when it already exists is also not possible.

Comment: @Larnu - If you can tell me another trigger to use that will kick off once the table is created and the insert is complete then I'm open to other options. Unfortunately I have no control over how I get the data... It is pushed to me from another org in my company. They drop the old table and recreate a new table every day... I'd much prefer another method for that as well but I don't have control over that. :(

Comment: A trigger is part of the DDL/DML process, @TheGambill . It doesn't happen *after* the transaction, it runs as part of it, and the DML/DDL statement will only finish after the trigger has too. Like I said, this seems like an XY problem, and what we really need to find out is the problem your trying to solve, not how to complete the solution you've started (which probably isn't the right solution).

Comment: the problem is:
I have other events that I need to occur after the table is completed. 
Currently we have a job that runs do do this. I'd like the events that occur in the job to run immediately after the table finishes instead of at a specific time.

Comment: SO... I asked the org that pushes the data to add a record to a table log after the insert is complete.  I created my trigger off of that and it seems to be working well now.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with a trigger.  If you need to know when a CRUD operation on a table is complete, you would need to execute a command after the CRUD operation in the same process that launches it.

Comment: So if that operation is controlled externally from a server that is pushing the data to me then I can't do this and I'll have to continue to do it at a specific time?

Comment: Correct, if data is being pushed to you from an external process that you can't control, there is no programmatic way on the receiving end to know when the push is complete.